# Web session timeout VS OAuth2 Implicit token expiration

Tags: rest, api, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, openid-connect

I am moving a monolithic application to micro services architecture, and all new API's will be authenticated/authorized by **OpenID Connect** and **OAuth2 implicit flow**.

OAuth2 implicit specification defines that there's no refresh token for this kind of flow. So, is there any way to renew an API token while a web session is still alive?

Some market providers offer API's with no time expiration during token generation, but in my opinion that's a bad practice. Even a "Single Page Application" should be aware when a OAuth token has expired forcing users to enter their credentials again in a login pop-up.

My question is how to keep a sync between a web session timeout and an API token expiration? Cause while a user session is active the token would never expire too.

Comment: You could set  the Session ttl to be a little lower than the Token ttl. So whrn the session expires you could regenerate the token

Comment: Yes, still this way a user will have to re-enter their credentials get a new token. Is there any way to only renew the token without having to redirect user to user loogin popup?